# Update/Edit multi user of visual svn

Tags: windows, authentication, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'm using Visual SVN 2.1.2
Last year my company used domain called 'VID'. This year, all of us change to new domain called 'TNG'. So all of our users using old username (ex: 'VID\JohnCena') cannot connect to server anymore. (They must use username like 'TNG\JohnCena')

So, is there any way to change/edit/update all users in all Reposotories from VID domain to TNG domain in their username ? All permission still the same, of course.

Ex: In this picture, I had to add TNG\lamnt3 by manual, but I cannot do this for all user. Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. I see some unresolved SID's on the screenshot. Investigate why these accounts are not in your AD anymore. This may indicate problems with your AD.
2. Upgrade the server to the latest VisualSVN Server 3.5 version. VisualSVN Server 2.x is very old and is not supported anymore.